# Should I queue a Nmodbus4 RTU connection by Mutex?

Tags: c#, mutex, modbus

I use library NModbus4 and create RTU connection.

```
public static IModbusSerialMaster Master { get; set; }
Master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(SerialPort);
```

I have method `GetClient()`which return `Master` and Method `Registers()` which look like:

```
    public static ushort[] Registers(Func<IModbusSerialMaster, ushort[]> action)
    {
        ushort[] registers = new ushort[0];
        var client = GetClient();
        if (client == null)
            return registers;
        //mutex.WaitOne();
        try
        {                
            registers = action.Invoke(client);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("error");
        }
        finally
        {
            //mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
        return registers;
    }
```

I was trying to use `System.Threading.Mutex`to be sure that only one method will send frames at a time. But after about minute when In loop are run 2/3 task it locks on `mutex.WaitOne();` and stop program.

If I not using mutex. I do not see any mistakes. Does NModbus itself ensure that the program does not crash in this way? Or I should find why is this happening, leave a mutex and fix the error?

Comment: You should use synchronization only if the method can be called by more than one thread at a time.