# C# Modbus: ReadHoldingRegisters not consistent in returning ouput

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus

I'm trying to search for a modbus that is connected to a serial port on my device and run some commands against it. However it seems to be that it is rather inconsistent at reading the holding registers. I'm using the `NModbus4` library.

I have a thread running every second that checks for available serial ports and tries to get a connection:

```
// === Check if port is open, start connecting procedure if closed
if (!(serialPort.IsOpen))
{
    List<string> portnames = new List<string>();

    foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
    {
        portnames.Add(s); // COM3
     }

     // === Loop through the listed ports and try to connect
     foreach (string portname in portnames)
     {
         if (!(serialPort.IsOpen))
         {
             try
             {
                 serialPort.PortName = portname;
                 serialPort.BaudRate = 57600;
                 serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                 serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                 serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.Two;

                 serialPort.Open();
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
              }
          }
      }
  }

  // === Check again after connecting procedure if the port is open
  if (serialPort.IsOpen)
  {
      // === Check number of open ports
      if (SerialPort.GetPortNames().Count() != 0)
      {
          // === Check if master is defined
          if (master == null)
          {
               // === Define master
               master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(serialPort);
          }

          // === If master is already defined
          if (master != null)
          {
               int parameterID = this.readParameterSetID();
               if (parameterID != 0)
               {
                    if (!desk_devices.Contains(parameterID))
                    {
                          desk_devices.Add(parameterID);
                          newDevice = true;
                    }
                }
           }
       } else
       {
            // === No serial ports available, close the opened serial port                    
            serialPort.Close();
       }
   }
```

The `readParameterSetID` function is as following:

```
private int readParameterSetID()
    {
        int parameterSetID = 0;

        if (mutex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---Poll overrun----");
        }

        mutex = true;
        if (serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            if (master != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ushort[] holding_register = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(1, 107, 1); // Fails here

                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        int tmpStart = Convert.ToInt32(107 + i);
                        String tempStart = Convert.ToString(tmpStart, 16);

                        int tmpReg = Convert.ToInt32(holding_register[i]);
                        String tempReg = Convert.ToString(tmpReg, 16);

                        parameterSetID = holding_register[i];
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        mutex = false;
        return parameterSetID;
    }
```

Now the weird thing happening here is that the `readParameterSetID` function should return a 7 or a 0 when executed correctly. However sometimes it just stops after reading the holding registers. `mutex` will stay true and nothing gets returned. When I reboot the application it either works or the same thing happens again.

I don't know why it's working in 50% of the situations and the other 50% returns nothing. I've tried to redefine the `master` if the function `readParameterSetID` fails, however I noticed that once every couple second the master will be reset resulting in commands further down the line not being send.

I'd love to know why this is happening or a way to fix this and read the holding registers without the communication failing.

Comment: Is it the problem that you are trying to find the serial port dynamically? Since the hardware will not be changed frequently, it is recommended to set the information of the serial port to be used in the configuration file.

Comment: @kunif Not really, finding the hardware dynamically works like a charm. I have created a demo application which connects the hardware using a button and then reads out the parameterSetID but then I get the same result, it only works a number of times. Manufacturer of the hardware told me that the hardware isn't the issue but the software is...

Comment: If that's what you want, forget my comment. There are other articles like this. [Should I queue a Nmodbus4 RTU connection by Mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63521366/9014308), [Handling modbus rtu frame in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62772162/9014308) It's unresolved, but some information may be available. Or, [Modbus with C#: libraries, code, utilities and examples](https://www.mesta-automation.com/modbus-with-c-sharp-libraries-examples/)